# Widget size 4x2 appearing 3x2

Tags: android, android-widget

I have 4x2 widget but on the Samsung galaxy tab, I am getting as 3x2.
minWidth = 250dp
minHeight = 110dp
its a 7inch, mdpi tablet.

On all other hdpi, mdpi, ldpi phones, I am getting 4x2 size for the widget.

Can someone please tell me whats going wrong. Am I missing something.

Thanks
rj12info

Comment: did the phone install any custom theme ?

Comment: @Shivan Raptor - Galaxy tab has no custom theme. Neither do any of the phones

Comment: incorrect. All Android phones can install custom theme.

Comment: @Shivan Raptor - I think there is a default wallpaper set, supposed to be a default theme on all phones. But my problem is on tablet. On tablet again its default wallpaper with default theme. No rooting done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working on samsung tab with 4x2 with old widget size formula.

I referred old documentation for calculating 4x2

width_of_widget = (4* 74) - 2 
height_of_widget = (2* 74) - 2

After 1 weekm struggle